# Пагинация страниц при выводе из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день!

Вывожу данные из таблицы в таблицу на страницу в таблицу:

```
$qr_result = mysql_query("select `id`,`u`,`a`,`s`,`type` from  board WHERE type = '1'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        $qr_result14 = mysql_query("select `id`,`u`,`a`,`s`,`type` from  board WHERE type = '2'")
    or die(mysql_error());
         $qr_result15 = mysql_query("select `id`,`u`,`a`,`s`,`type` from  board WHERE type = '3'")
        or die(mysql_error());
       $qr_result16 = mysql_query("select `id`,`u`,`a`,`s`,`type` from  board WHERE type = '4' ")
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Данные выводятся относительно столбца type несколько раз из одной таблицы. Подскажите, как сделать постраничный вывод (пагинацию).

Answer (score 1):

Делаете два запроса. Один считает только count(*) элементов, второй выводит все остальное
с установленным limit START, AMOUNT.

Что-то типа

```
select count(*) from board WHERE type = '1';

select id,u,a,s,type from board WHERE type = '1' limit $pageNum, $perPage;
```

$pageNum - номер страницы, на единицу меньше реального, $perPage - количество элементов на странице.

P.S.:

```
or die(mysql_error())
```

Плохо, очень плохо.

```
$qr_result 
$qr_result14 
$qr_result15
$qr_result16
```

Тоже никому не показывайте, что не умеете... хотя бы циклами пользоваться, что ли.